# Java 8 Optional get() method

Tags: java, option-type

Is using get() method in this fashion the recommended approach when using Optional?

```
Optional<User> loginUser = userService.findUserByEmail(authentication.getName());

if (loginUser.isPresent()) {
  User user = loginUser.get();
  user.setLastLogin(new Date());
  userService.saveUser(user);   
}
```

Comment: That's one way to use it, although in this particular scenario it offers little advantage over using `null` (except maybe documenting the code that it can possibly return an empty result instead of throwing an exception for example).

Comment: The question is, what should happen if the end user is not logged in?  Do you want the application to just keep going like nothing is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
loginUser.ifPresent(user -> {
    user.setLastLogin(new Date());
    userService.saveUser(user);
});
```

More elegant. Here's more to the topic: [isPresent() is bad for you.](https://dzone.com/articles/optional-ispresent-is-bad-for-you)

Comment: isPresent() is (sometimes) bad, but your code is just doing the same thing with a different syntax.